# Search window in Desktop ArcGIS 10.3.1 not opening after Windows 10 update?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, windows-10, search-window

My computer has been running Windows 10 for almost a year and I haven't noticed issues with ArcGIS until the most recent update. Now the search window in 10.3.1 is not opening when I click the icon. There is no indication that ArcGIS is doing anything or recognizing the action in any way.

Comment: I'm assuming by "Search Tool" you mean the Search window rather than the Find Tool.

Comment: It looks like you are using a certified configuration: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/get-started/system-requirements/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm

Comment: If you have been using two monitors perhaps check that it is not currently off the one you are using.

Comment: I'm using only one monitor.

Comment: unfortunately same problem on 10.4.1...

Answer (score 1):

I could not figure out a way to fix this problem in 10.3.1 so I ended up uninstalling ArcGIS. I then updated to 10.4 and it was no longer an issue.